# Converting pandas column values to colums

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with column values which I want to combine with the existing columns. Here is an example dataframe and the desired result. Any ideas how I could create the result_df?

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'city' : ['New York','New York', 'Shanghai', 'Shanghai', 'Boston', 'Boston'],
 'rooms': ["1","2","1","2","1", "2"], 'rent': [500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500 ,3000]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)

result = {'city' : ['New York', 'Shanghai','Boston'],
   'rent_1': [500, 1500, 2500], 'rent_2': [1000, 2000, 3000]}

result_df = pd.DataFrame(data = result)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `pd.crosstab` with `.add_prefix`

```
df1 = pd.crosstab(df['city'],df['rooms'],
            df['rent'],aggfunc=lambda x : x)\
            .add_prefix('rent_')\
            .reset_index().rename_axis("",axis=1)
```

---

```
print(df1)

       city  rent_1  rent_2
0    Boston    2500    3000
1  New York     500    1000
2  Shanghai    1500    2000
```

---

or use `.unstack()`

```
df.set_index(['city','rooms']).unstack(1).add_prefix('rent_').droplevel(0,1)\
   .reset_index().rename_axis("",axis=1)


  city  rent_1  rent_2
0    Boston    2500    3000
1  New York     500    1000
2  Shanghai    1500    2000
```

Answer (score 0):

`df.pivot_table(values=["rent"], index=["city"], columns=["rooms"])`

[image: output]